# Group action on finite set of integers: is it necessarily a permutation group?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

I'm just starting to learn about group actions and there is something not clear to me.

Let $S = \{1, \dots, n\}$ and let $G$ be a group acting on $S$.

> Does this imply that $G$ is a permutation group, that is, that $G
>  \subseteq S_n$ where $S_n$ is the symmetric group? Or could $G$ be any
>    group like e.g. the Klein 4 group?

Comment: An action of $G$ on $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ is the same thing as a homomorphism from $G \to S_n = Aut \{1, \ldots, n\}$. If the action is faithful, meaning that the only group element that fixes all the letters is the identity, then this gives an embedding of $G$ into $S_n$. In particular, if you let a finite group $G$ act on its elements, this gives an embedding of G into $S_n$, for $n = |G|$.

Comment: The braid group $B_n$ has a natural action $B_n\to S_n$. It's an infinite group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given any set $S$, any group $G$ can act on $S$ via the trivial action ($gs=s$ for all $g\in G$ and $s\in S$). Thus, ***any*** group can act on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, regardless of whether it is an actual, literal subset of $S_n$ (the group of permutations of the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$).

On the other hand, every group does **embed** in (i.e., have an injective homomorphism to) some group of permutations, namely, the group of permutations of its underlying set:
$$\varphi:G\longrightarrow S_G,\qquad \varphi(g)=\text{ the permutation }\sigma:G\to G \text{ defined by }\sigma(h)=gh$$
Thus, for example, if $G$ is a group with $n$ elements, then we can naturally **view** $G$ as a subgroup of $S_n$. This result is usually called Cayley's theorem ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem)).

Comment: Thank you, so just to check that I understand: $G$ is not a subgroup but definitely isomorphic to some subgroup of $S_n$ and therefore we may as well consider the elements of $G$ to be permutations?

Comment: @astudent: That's correct, but be careful, because there exist actions that are not **faithful** ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Types_of_actions)). For example, let $G=S_4$, which (as I've said) can act on any set whatsoever via the trivial action. In particular $G$ can act on the set $\{1,2,3\}$. Observe that this doesn't imply $G$ can be viewed as a subgroup of $S_3$, since that's impossible ($S_4$ is bigger than $S_3$). The result I am saying is that $G$ can be viewed as a subgroup of $S_{24}$ (note that $24=|G|=4!$).

Comment: Thank you for your help, your answer is really excellent. Just one more question: Does this apply to infinite groups too? Say, $G$ is $\mathbb Z$, does it make sense to say the group of permutations of the underlying set?

Comment: @astudent: Yup, it does. For any set $X$ whatsoever, finite or infinite, one can form the group of permutations of it, usually known as "the symmetric group on the set $X$", written
$$S_X\;\overset{\text{def}}{=}\;\{\text{bijective functions }f:X\to X\}$$
Then Cayley's theorem is saying that any group $G$ can be considered as a subgroup of the symmetric group on the set $G$.